# Could not open input file: composer.phar

Tags: yii2, composer

Помогите пожалуйста с проблемой. Не могу установить php файл в корень проекта с помощью composer. Вообще что связано с composer не устанавливается. Выкидывает ошибку:

```
u*******@u*******.cp.regruhosting.ru [~/public_html/example.com]# composer require dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset "^2.1"
Could not open input file: /var/www/u*******/composer.phar
```

Я уже всё перепробовала, что можно было и даже нельзя..
Может кто-то сталкивался с этим? В чём может быть беда?

Comment: Существует ли этот файл? Что скажет `ls /var/www/u*******/composer.phar`?

Comment: @sanmai этот файл существует в корневой директории самого сайта.. А по пути /var/www/u0498223/ нет такого файла. То есть его там нужно установить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно скопировать `composer.phar` в каталог, в котором он ожидается что будет находиться. В вашем случае это `/var/www/u0498223/`.

Либо, если `composer.phar` находится в известном каталоге, его можно запускать по прямому пути явно:

```
php composer.phar install
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное. Оказалось всё так банально.. а я на это потратила целых 2 дня..((

Comment: А лучше установите composer глобально в систему.